# En python con que tecla hago para ver los comandos que tiene un objeto

Tags: python

Por ejemplo con numpy, si yo le doy "numpy." despues del . quiero ver la lista de comando que tiene, antes lo hacia con la tecla tabulador pero no me esta funcionando ya, o no recuerdo bien, estoy usando el idle 3.6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te refieres al autocompletado de código este funciona simplemente esperando 2 segundos después del `.` o bién usando `Ctrl + Espacio`. Se puede cambiar el tiempo de espera y desactivar/activar el autocompletado en:

> Options > Configure IDLE > Extensions

El problema con NumPy y otras librerias que no usa el propio IDLE para su funcionamiento es que el autocompletado no está disponible porque no está presente en espacio de nombres en el que se evalúa el nombre que se va a completar ya que el módulo no ha sido importado en esa sesión del IDLE. Esto ocurre en el editor de código, no en el shell o intérprete interactivo. Si te interesa puedes mirarte esta [incidencia](http://bugs.python.org/issue18766) en el Bug tracker de Python.

La solución es abrir una ventana del intérprete interactivo (*Run > Python Shell*)

y importas en él los mísmos módulos y de la misma forma que haces en el editor.

Algo más sencillo es que cuando tengas todos los import escritos ejecutes el script pulsando F5 o en *"Run > Run Module"* y luego **no cierres la ventana del intérprete interactivo donde se ejecuta**, si lo haces el autocompletado no funcionará.

Con eso obtenemos lo que creo que quieres:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla !! :D

Answer (score 1):

Mira el menú "Edit/Show Completions", el atajo es Control + Espacio.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html